# Disk Partitioning for ubuntu 15.10 to have a NTFS drive

Tags: partitioning, ntfs

I have a 500 GB HDD. I want to install ubuntu 15.10 on it and also want to have an NTFS partition on the drive. What would be the best partitioning scheme for it?

Comment: I am not creating a windows ubuntu dual boot pc

Comment: Do you have any existing OS atm?

Answer (score 0):

Use gparted.  This is available on the Live ubuntu install disk.

With this gui application you can create new partitions, resize any existing partitions, or delete partitions and more.

Decide how big you want your Ubuntu partition to be and how big you want your Windows partition to be.  Also create a swap drive.  Your swap drive should be at least the size of the ram you have in your computer.  You might consider making it 1.5 times amount in case you increase your ram in the future.

When installing your OS'es both Ubuntu and Windows, you will have the option during install to choose the specific partition for the install.

Keep in mind that in the normal legacy mode a disk can only have 4 primary partitions.  You might consider making one primary partition, then and extended partition.  Under the extended partition you can create as many partitions as you want.  This way you can have partitions for your OS installs, a swap partition and other DATA partitions.

Comment: I am not creating a dual boot system. I just want to know the best partition scheme.